# Page is changed but the content remain same in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

The problem is that I load dynamically menu pages from database. And whenever I click on the page load only page_id=1 and content... For example if I click `page_id=5` will load again first result from database table. In browser address bar I see that id is changed but not on the page.

This is what I have so far.. route

```
Route::get ('/static/page/{pageId}', ['uses' => 'HomeController@page']);
```

In HomeController page looks like this

```
public function page() {

          $pages = Pages::all();
          return View::make('site.page', [            
              'pages' => $pages
          ]); 
}
```

in page.blade.php I have this

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@foreach($pages as $page)
    @section('title', $page->page_title)

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>{{ $page->page_title }}</h3>
        <hr />

        <div class="row">
            {{ $page->page_body }}
        </div>

        <hr />
    </div>
    @endsection
@endforeach
```

Button which lead to page.blade

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::to('/static/page/'.$page->page_id) }}">{{ $page->page_title }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the pageID anywhere. You need to pass it into the function, then use it in the query.

```
public function page($pageID) {

      $page = Pages::findOrFail($pageID);
      return View::make('site.page', [            
          'pages' => $page
      ]); 
}
```

Then you can use the single page object on your page.blade.php.

Comment: Thank's but now I get this `'Trying to get property of non-object...` here `@foreach($pages as $page)` in page.blade.php

Comment: You no longer need the foreach. If you need a list of articles on one page and the article to show on another, use different blade files. You can use the same function and redirect them based on if the `$pageID` is set or not.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank's for the help!